# how can I pass the data that is passed in a form to a json file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm working with nodejs, I have an crud app for storing data, I want to pass the data to a main json file.
my files are like this:

index.js

```
'use strict'

const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

app.get("/", ( req, res) => {
    res.render("home.ejs");
})

app.listen((3000), ()=> {
    console.log("listening on port 3000..");
})
```

home.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- page title -->
  <title>Sellers - Added</title>
  <!-- bootstrap css -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- local css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- main wrapper start -->
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <!-- title start -->
    <div class="title text-center">
      <h1 class="display-5">
        <i class="fas fa-user-alt text-success"></i> <strong>Sellers List</strong>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- title end -->

    <!-- content start -->
    <div class="main row">

      <!-- left form start -->
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <!-- page form -->
        <form id="seller-form" autocomplete="off">

          <!-- seller name start -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Seller Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <!-- seller name end -->

          <!-- seller domain start -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="domain">Domain:</label>
            <input type="text" id="domain" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <!-- seller domain end -->

          <!-- seller type start -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type">Seller Type:</label>
            <input type="text" id="type" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <!-- seller type end -->

          <!-- submit button start -->
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block add-btn">
          <!-- submit button end -->

        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- left form end -->
      
      <!-- list start -->
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
        <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Domain</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="seller-list"></tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- list end -->
    </div>
    <!-- content end -->
  </div>
  <!-- main wrapper end -->


</body>
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

script.js

```
let selectedRow = null; 


class Seller {
  constructor(name, domain, type, id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.domain = domain;
    this.type = type;
    this.id = id;
  }
}

// UI Class: Handle UI Tasks
class UI {
  // add seller to list
  static addSellerToList(seller) {

    const list = document.querySelector('#seller-list');
    const row = document.createElement('tr');

    row.innerHTML = `
      <td>${seller.name}</td>
      <td>${seller.domain}</td>
      <td>${seller.type}</td>
      <td>${seller.id}</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm edit">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">X</a></td>
    `;

    list.appendChild(row);
  }

  // edit seller to list
  static editSellerToList(seller) {
    selectedRow.children[0].textContent = seller.name;
    selectedRow.children[1].textContent = seller.domain;
    selectedRow.children[2].textContent = seller.type;
  }

  // delete seller
  static deleteSeller(el) {
    if(el.classList.contains('delete')) {
      el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
      UI.showAlert('Seller Deleted', 'danger');
    } else null
  }

  // edit seller
  static editSeller(el) {
    if(el.classList.contains('edit')) {
      selectedRow = el.parentElement.parentElement;
      document.querySelector('#name').value = selectedRow.children[0].textContent;
      document.querySelector('#domain').value = selectedRow.children[1].textContent;
      document.querySelector('#type').value = selectedRow.children[2].textContent;
    } else null
  }

  static showAlert(message, className) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = `alert alert-${className}`;
    
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    const container = document.querySelector('.container');
    const main = document.querySelector('.main');
    container.insertBefore(div, main);
    setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.alert').remove(), 2000);
  }

  static clearFields() {
    document.querySelector('#name').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#domain').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#type').value = '';
  }
}

// Store Class: Handles Storage
// class Store {
//   static getSellers() {
//     let sellers;
//     if(localStorage.getItem('sellers') === null) {
//       sellers = [];
//     } else {
//       sellers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sellers'));
//     }

//     return sellers;
//   }

//   static addSeller(seller) {
//     const sellers = Store.getSellers();
//     sellers.push(seller);
//     localStorage.setItem('sellers', JSON.stringify(sellers));
//   }

//   static removeSeller(type) {
//     const sellers = Store.getSellers();

//     sellers.forEach((seller, index) => {
//       if(seller.type === type) {
//         sellers.splice(index, 1);
//       }
//     });

//     localStorage.setItem('sellers', JSON.stringify(sellers));
//   }
// }

// Event: Display Sellers
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',UI.displaySellers);

// Event: Add a Seller
document.querySelector('#seller-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  // Prevent actual submit
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get form values
  
  const name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
  const domain = document.querySelector('#domain').value;
  const type = document.querySelector('#type').value;
  const id = GenerateUniqueID();

  // Validate
  
  if(name === '' || domain === '' || type === '') {
    UI.showAlert('Please fill in all fields', 'danger');
  } else {
    // Instatiate seller
    const seller = new Seller(name, domain, type, id);
  if (selectedRow == null) {
    // Add Seller to UI
    UI.addSellerToList(seller);
    selectedRow = null;
    UI.showAlert('Seller Added', 'success');
  } else {
    UI.editSellerToList(seller);
    selectedRow = null;
    UI.showAlert('Seller Info Edited', 'info');
  }
    // Add seller to store
    // Store.addSeller(seller);
    // Show success message
    // Clear fields
    UI.clearFields();
  }
});

// Event: Remove a Seller
document.querySelector('#seller-list').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Remove seller from UI
  UI.deleteSeller(e.target);
  UI.editSeller(e.target);
  // Remove seller from store
  // Store.removeSeller(e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent);
  // Show success message
  // UI.showAlert('Seller Removed', 'success');
});

function GenerateUniqueID() {
  return ('0000'+(Math.random() * (100000 - 101) + 101)|0).toString().slice(-5);
}
```

again, I just need the data to save to a new json file.
any help is very appriciated, thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly is your problem? We need to see the code you'd like us to assist you with. This site is for programming help, not to provide code according to a set of task requirements. I suggest you to read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you.

Comment: hey man, just where the form is as you can see in home.ejs I need to pass the data to a json file